# platform IOのバグっぽい動作の報告先

Tags: esp32

[先日の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69594/esp32%E7%94%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0vs-code%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AEpaltformio%E3%81%A7-%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E9%80%9A%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) はひょんな事から解決したのですが、こちらの修正はどうも PlatformIO のバグというか、多分英語圏の人だと気付いていない問題みたいなのですが、どのように報告するのが良いのでしょうか。

正直言って英語でこういうのを報告したことがなくて・・・

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlatformIO に関しては GitHub 上でソースコードが管理されており、問題の起きている箇所は [platformio-core](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-core) のリポジトリに含まれるもののようなので、[Issues](https://github.com/platformio/platformio-core/issues) から報告してみるとよいでしょう。
("cp932" で検索した限りは未報告のようです)

報告用のテンプレートも用意されているので、そちらを埋める形で進めてみてください。
私個人も英語は全く自信ありませんが、機械翻訳を使いながらでもなんとかなります (相手も常にネイティブの英語話者とは限りません)

Comment: ありがとうございます。週末にちょっとやってみます

Comment: 直後にplatform IOのバージョンアップがあって、修正されてました